# yum install httpd-devel on mediatemple dv 4

Tags: centos, yum, mediatemple

I have a mediatemple dv 4 with plesk 11.0.9 installed.

When I run yum install httpd-devel I get the following

```
httpd-devel-2.2.3-76.el5.centos.x86_64 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-76.el5.centos is needed by package httpd-devel-2.2.3-76.el5.centos.x86_64 (updates)
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-76.el5.centos is needed by package httpd-devel-2.2.3-76.el5.centos.x86_64 (updates)
```

This is the httpd version installed:

```
 * atomic: www6.atomicorp.com
 * base: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: centos.aol.com
 * updates: mirror.lug.udel.edu
Installed Packages
Name       : httpd
Arch       : x86_64
Epoch      : 1
Version    : 2.2.22
Release    : 12053112
Size       : 3.5 M
Repo       : installed
Summary    : The Apache HTTP Server
License    : Apache Software License
Description: The Apache HTTP Server is a powerful, efficient, and extensible
           : web server.
```

How can I get the correct version of httpd-devel to go with this version of httpd?

Comment: Do you actually have httpd installed

Comment: yes, It's a working web server fresh out of the box from mediatemple

Answer (score 1):

Your server has an `httpd` package installed that doesn't match that in *any* of the repositories you currently have. It is also *newer* than that in *any* of the repositories you currently have. Interestingly, its source isn't identified there in your `yum info` output. You might find more information about the package with `rpm -qi httpd`.

To resolve the issue, you can do one of two things:

1. Get rid of any installed packages which don't match your installed repositories and resync your system's installed packages to the packages which *are* available. This can be accomplished with a single command:

   ```
   yum distro-sync
   ```
2. Discover the source of the `httpd` package you have, and then install the repository configuration for that repo. This might be more difficult.